# Is $f(x) = 1/x$ over $[0.1 , 1]$ uniformly continuous but $1/x$ on $(0,1)$ is not?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

I know that there is a theorem that says that "Every continuous function on a bounded closed interval $[a,b]$ is uniformly continuous therein."

But I know that the function $f(x) = 1/x$ defined on (0,1) is not uniformly continuous (I know how to prove this). Does the previous theorem is saying that $f(x) = 1/x$ defined on [0.1,1] is uniformly continuous? why? what should I change in my proof of being not uniform continuous.

Here is my proof of not being uniformly continuous:

Let $\delta > 0,$ take $\epsilon = 1$ and $x = \min \{1, \delta\}$ and $a = \frac{x}{2}.$ then $|x - a | = |x - x/2| = \frac{x}{2} < \delta$ but $|\frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{x}| = |\frac{2}{x} - \frac{1}{x}| = \frac{1}{x} > 1.$ And so $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

Also, my justification that it is continuous because it is the division of 2 polynomials (and in this justification I do not see any use of open or closed intervals)

Could anyone help me in answering my questions, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is uniformly continuous on $[0.1;1]$ and yes, it is not uniformly continuous on $(0;1)$. Which is the part that confuses you? Maybe it helps to note that $(0;1)$ is not of the form $[a;b]$ and so the theorem about uniform continuity does not apply.

Comment: Your proof breaks, predictably, when $\delta<0.1$.

Comment: The way that proving uniform continuity works is that you choose the epsilon *first*, and then you find a suitable delta. Not the other way around.

Comment: You are looking at $x=\min \{ 1, \delta \}$ and $a=x/2$.  These are outside the domain $[0.1, 1]$ if $\delta$ is too small.

Comment: This may be confusing because $(0,1)$ looks like the closed interval $[0.1,1]$ but it's really not.  $(0,1)$ since it has no endpoints can be stretched out indefinitely, and functions can do crazy things over a long enough interval.  However $[0.1,1]$ with its bounds will still be "small" no matter how you try to stretch it out.

Comment: A short note: A function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous iff $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)$ exist finitely.

Comment: @K.defaoite"The way that proving uniform continuity works is that you choose the epsilon first, and then you find a suitable delta. Not the other way around. " But the OP is proving it is NOT uniform continuous by finding a counter example: for $\epsilon=1$ there is no $\delta$ that will suffice.  The OPs proof for $(0,1)$ is fine.  But it breaks down on $[0.1,1]$.

Comment: "I do not see any use of open or closed intervals"  When you assume $x > 0$ but $x \ne 0$ and that $\frac x2$ will be acceptable in that  $\frac x2 > 0; \frac x2\in(0,1)$ that is assuming there an "open end" at $(0,$.   You can not do that with assuming $x\ge 0.1$ for $[0.1,1]$.  If $0.1\le x < 0.2$ then $\frac x2 < 0.1$ and $\frac x2 \not \in [0.1,1]$.  Failure.

Comment: @StinkingBishop can you please tell me why my proof breaks?

Comment: @mjqxxxx thank you so much for your comment, it helped me a lot!

Comment: @D_S if you gave me an example with concrete numbers it will be great.

Comment: @Brain Because with $\delta<0.1$ both $x=\min(1,\delta)<0.1$ and even more: $\frac{x}{2}<0.1$ so both $x$ and $\frac{x}{2}$ fall out of the domain $[0.1,1]$ of the function. Thus you cannot disprove uniform continuity using that argument (and in fact, as others have said, you cannot disprove it at all, because it *is* true.)

Comment: @SujitBhattacharyya and so ?

Comment: @fleablood amazing explanation in your second comment, thank you very much!

Comment: One essential difference between $[0.1,1]$ and $(0,1)$ that should have hit you like a 2 by 4 in the head, even if you don't know what to do with it is that as $x\to 0$ then $\frac 1x \to \infty$ and gets infinitely big.  But on $[0.1,1]$ then $x\to 0.1$ then $\frac 1x \to 10$ and $\frac 1x \le 10$ is very limited. It's not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$ because tiny changes in $x$ close to $0$ can make huge changes in $\frac 1x$ but tiny changes in $x$ near but above $0.1$ can only make changes as high as $10$ and we can squish these changes small with proper restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Uniform Continuous function

To understand it clearly, you should think what uniform continuity looks like. Let me illustrate it.

Given function is:
$f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$

**Claim:** In the interval (0, 1), you cannot find  $\delta$ corresponding to  any $\epsilon$.

To understand this, fix  $\epsilon = 1$, and choose whatever $\delta$ you think will satisfy the definition. You will find that this will not work. Reduce $\delta$ by half. You will find this will also not work. Keep on dividing it by half. You will  find  that no such $\delta$ works.

This happens because  $f$ grows too fast in the neighbourhood of 0 so that no such $\delta$ sized sub-interval of (0, 1) can capture the growth of $f$.

In the case of interval [0.1, 1], there is no such neighborhood where $f$ grows rapidly (which is true for continuous functions on closed and bounded intervals), therefore you can find a $\delta>0$ corresponding to every $\epsilon>0$.

**How to find $\delta$ corresponding to $\epsilon$ in the interval [0.1, 1]:**

Choose an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$.
$|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}| = \frac{|x-y|}{|xy|}$

Using the fact that $x, y \geq 0.1$,
$|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}| = \frac{|x-y|}{|xy|} \leq 100 |x-y| < \epsilon$

Clearly, $\delta  = \frac{\epsilon}{100}$

Comment: Can you give me the way of how to find the $\delta$ in case of the interval $[0.1,1]$ please?

Comment: Yes, sure. In this case $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{100}$.

Let choose an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$.

$|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}| = \frac{|x-y|}{|xy|}$.

Using the fact that $x, y \geq 0.1$,  
$|\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{y}| = \frac{|x-y|}{|xy|} \leq 100 |x-y| < \epsilon$.

Clearly, $\delta  = \frac{\epsilon}{100}$

Answer (score 1):

$$\left|\frac1{x-\delta}-\frac1x\right|=\left|\frac{\delta}{(x-\delta)x}\right|<\epsilon$$ requires

$$\delta<\frac{\epsilon x^2}{\epsilon x+1}<\epsilon x^2$$ so that no finite bound can hold for all $x$.

Comment: it is not clear to me which case are you considering, could you clarify please?

Comment: @Brain: case ? What case ? (In fact the absolute value is superfluous, as $\delta<x$ is implicit, but I preferred to keep it to have a familiar expression.)

Comment: I mean uniform continuous proof or non-uniform continuous proof.

Comment: @Brain: come on, "for all $x$" says it.